# Modifying the title bar of any application in Windows 10?

Tags: windows

Some programs like for example TeamViewer add a custom button to the title bar of all Windows. How do they accomplish that?

I am particularly interested how this can be done in Windows 10. Is it only buttons or anything can be added/drawn to/on the title bar?

**Edit:** Is the Universal Windows Platform (WinRT) relevant?

Comment: Using the `CreateWindow` function with the style parameter including `WS_CHILD`, you could create 'buttons' on each window.

Comment: No, this is universally done, TeamViewer too by the looks of it, by **not** using the built-in title bar.  A borderless window, you can make it look like anything you want.  And a bunch of code to restore the built-in behavior you lost, never completely perfect.  The kind of nicety you can afford when you have dozens of programmers working on a product.

Comment: @HansPassant Do you mean they are somehow replacing the title bar system wide with a custom one?